# How to add dynamic routes in express server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, redux

I want to make some custom endpoints for my react application, using express as my "fake server"

I have a shopping application. for some products/checkouts I want to add coupons. they get "applied" in the frontend/react side, that makes a request to the backend/server. and then it either comes back saying "coupon is valid", and changes the price for me. or says "coupon is not valid"

I want to hit a dynamic endpoint like this:

```
app.get(`/product/${productId}/coupons`, function(req, res) {})
```

but obviously I can't do this as `productId` has not been defined. but is there anyway when I make my `axios.get` request this can build/inject a route for me. or how can I add "dynamic" routes in express to solve this problem?

Comment: looks like you are just trying to pass `productID` in url as a param ? in that case you should be able to do it with `app.get(`/product/:productId/coupons`..)` No ?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for are express router params, you can define them this way:

```
app.get(`/product/:productId/coupons`, function(req, res) {})
```

And `productId` will be available inside the route handler as a property of `req.params`.

More info in the official docs: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters